# jsf get selectOneMenu value from actionListener of h:commandButton

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, row, addition

I have a primefaces datatable with the attribute editable="true" so I can't edit the rows dynamically. I have two fields: an inputText and a selectOneMenu. I want to be able to add rows dynamically from the footer. I added empty field in the footer and when the user click a button, I want to add the new line to the datatable with the correct values.

Here is the code I have:

```
<h:form>
...
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.myObjects}" id="myDatatable" editable="true" var="obj">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="My Datatable" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="My String value">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{obj.myString}" />
            </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{obj.myString}"/>
           </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.myNewObject.myString}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="My List Value">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.myListValue ? 'yes' : 'no'}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.myListValue}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="yes" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="no" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.myNewObject.myListValue}" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="yes" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="no" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor />

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.addRow}">
                <f:ajax execute="myDatatable" render="myDatatable" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
...
</h:form>
```

In my bean, I just have this for the addRow method:

```
public void addRow() {
    this.myObjects.add(this.myNewObject);
    this.myNewObject = new MyObject();
}
```

and the init:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.myObjects = Controller.getAllMyObjects();
    this.myNewObject = new MyObject();
}
```

I could precise that the bean is in ViewScope. The result is that the line is added, the string value is correct but the list value is always "no" even if I set it to true with this.myNewObject.setMyListValue(true) in the bean after instanciate the object.

I know that this is something with to render or the execute of attributes.
If I change the line:

```
<f:ajax execute="myDatatable" render="myDatatable" />
```

to:

```
<p:ajax update="@form" />
```

the list value is true but the string value is not set.

How to be sure that both of my attribute are rendered and how can I get there values without submiting the whole form?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `<p:commandButton action="#{bean.addRow}" prcoess="myDatatable" update="myDatatable" />` in the footer instead of the `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax`.

Comment: Thank you but the result is the same. In fact, I think my problem is that the setter property of the field linked to the selectOneMenu is called twice, first time with correct value and second time with null value. And my field is a boolean that's why the result is always "false" (null casted to boolean return false). I have seen this issue and I think it's my problem... `https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4681`

Comment: Why are you using an `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` instead of a `p:commandButton`? In the footer of the `selectOneMenu` you are setting the value to `#{bean.myListValue}`, but later you are using `#{bean.myNewObject.myListValue}`, if this is actually in your code this could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I was using h:commandButton with f:ajax instead of p:commandButton. But is there a difference between them? And you were right, in my question I inverted the `bean.myListValue` and the `bean.myNewObject.myListValue` (I edited my post to correct it) but in my code, it's correct.

Comment: The problem is that the button and the `f:ajax` result in two different independent requests. The `f:ajax` will just rerender the datatable, this will be done when the given server side action is done, but as there is no action the rerender will be done immediately, so you will not get the updated info which you would like to display after `#{bean.addRow}`. Also you should use `action` instead of `actionListener`, as the response will be rendered after the `action`-method is done, so you can not be sure if the new item is already added when you get the response. It's simply the wrong way.

Comment: Okay thanks for all those precisions. However, my problem persists with the p:commandButton with action, process and update.